# Hi, I am new in JBPM7, I want to use Mysql in JBPM7 business process, Can any one please guide with steps or any sample examples

Tags: java, jbpm

I am new in JBPM7, I want to use Mysql in JBPM7 business process, Can any one please guide with steps or any sample examples.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this [link](https://jbpm.org/learn/gettingStarted.html) to kick start with jBPM and also demonstrates how to change the DB.